# How can I group by Linq statement

Tags: c#, linq

How can I group by this linq statement?

```
public IQueryable<Lottery> GetLotteriesByLotteryOfferId(int lotteryOfferId)
{
    return this.db.LotteryOffers
                                .Where(lo => lo.Id == lotteryOfferId)
                                .SelectMany(lo => lo.LotteryDrawDates)
                                .Select(ldd => ldd.Lottery);                                        
}
```

This doesn't work:

```
public IQueryable<Lottery> GetLotteriesByLotteryOfferId(int lotteryOfferId)
{
    return this.db.LotteryOffers
                                .Where(lo => lo.Id == lotteryOfferId)
                                .SelectMany(lo => lo.LotteryDrawDates)
                                .Select(ldd => ldd.Lottery)
                                .GroupBy(s => new { s.Name, s.CreatedBy, s.ModifiedOn, s.Id })
                                .Select(g => new Lottery
                                                {
                                                    Name = g.Key.Name,
                                                    CreatedBy = g.Key.CreatedBy,
                                                    ModifiedOn = g.Key.ModifiedOn,
                                                    Id = g.Key.Id
                                                });
}
```

Error that I get:

> The entity or complex type 'Lottery' cannot be constructed in a LINQ
>   to Entities query.

I use data service(web service).

Comment: And the problem or error???

Comment: What's the purpose of `group by` here?

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to SQL and LINQ to Entities - unlike LINQ to Objects and LINQ to Xml - uses the higher order methods to generate SQL that will be ran on the database, and therefore the lambdas don't have the full power of the language. Creating a new `Lottery` in the `Select` "clause" makes no sense - you don't want to create those `Lottery` objects in the database process, you want to create them in your application's process.

What you need to do is to use [`AsEnumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435.aspx):

```
 return this.db.LotteryOffers
                            .Where(lo => lo.Id == lotteryOfferId)
                            .SelectMany(lo => lo.LotteryDrawDates)
                            .Select(ldd => ldd.Lottery)
                            .GroupBy(s => new { s.Name, s.CreatedBy, s.ModifiedOn, s.Id })
                            .AsEnumerable()
                            .Select(g => new Lottery
                                            {
                                                Name = g.Key.Name,
                                                CreatedBy = g.Key.CreatedBy,
                                                ModifiedOn = g.Key.ModifiedOn,
                                                Id = g.Key.Id
                                            });
```

Everything before the `AsEnumerable` generates SQL. The call to `AsEnumerable` forces C# to execute the query and get the result as a stream of objects - something that `Select` can now use to generate your `Lottery` objects.

Comment: My point is that I want to return Count of rows when I group by, but then I have to use anonymous type, which I cannot in this case as you can see, because I use Data Service(Web service) and I need to return Type Lottery.

Comment: In that case, you might want to consider using [`Distinct`](http://csharp-guide.blogspot.co.il/2012/05/linq-to-sql-select-distinct-values.html) instead of `GroupBy`.

Comment: What are you trying to get a count for? Total number of Offers for a specific lottery?

Comment: Idan I used Distinct() but how can I create custom "field" so I can show Count in my view? **Abhijeet Patel** that is correct.

Comment: Abhijeet Patel, you know what I need :P I am hitting the wall whole day with this.

Comment: You want a custom field in the result of the method, or in each `Lottery` object?